# function from linux shell script not execute in c program

Tags: c, linux, system

I have seen similar posts in stackoverflow and other sites but I cannot find solution to my problem.

I have the  following `consoleout.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

#this way works in c:
#echo "Hello World!"

#but in function does not work:
a(){
  echo "Hello World!"
}
```

Following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system(".  consoleout.sh"); 

    system("a");
    return 0;
}
```

Without `system("./consoleout.sh")`, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `system` or code a program in C in such cases?

Answer (score 4):

`system()` invokes a shell and waits for it to terminate. Another call to `system()` will create a different shell that starts from scratch.

To run your shell function, you need to do it from the shell where it was defined:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    return system( ".  consoleout.sh; a" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each `system` calls a new instance of the shell, the second one doesn't know anything about the functions defined in the first one. You can, though, call the function in the first shell:

```
system(". consoleout.sh ; a");
```